# Subobject classifiers with a quantale structure

Tags: ct.category-theory, oa.operator-algebras, topos-theory, monoidal-categories

**Quantales** were kind of popular a few decades ago, as some sort of "quantum" version of the much more widespread concept of locale (Mulvey introduced them to study $C^*$ algebras). I was under the impression that they more or less faded away, but, much to my delight,  it looks like they are back (see for instance the interesting monograph by Pedro Resende [here](https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/%7Epmr/poci55958/gncg51gamap-version2.pdf)).

Somehow, since I found out about their existence, I had the idea that, just like in Topos Theory the structure of sub-objects (and thus also of their classifier) is a **Heyting Algebra**, some other sufficiently rich  categories, for instance some monoidal closed categories, should have a "sub-object classier" whose structure is that of a quantale.

Here is the question:

*Is there any category $C$ such that  it admits a contra-variant $SUB(-)$ functor
factoring through the category of quantales, and moreover such that $SUB(-)$ is representable by "characteristic maps" into a distinguished object $\Omega$ ?*

**PRE-EMPTIVE CLARIFICATION**: I am *not* interested in topoi with additional structure, so that the quantale  comes up on top of the underlying  heyting algebra. Rather, I would like the **sub-object functor to have a native quantale structure**. For fans of **Linear Logic**, I could say that I am interested in a category whose internal logic is linear in the full sense (any type, ie any object, has a quantale of predicates associated to it. Representability would extend the power to higher order linear logic)

**ADDENDUM**

Waiting for an answer, I have stumbled upon an old article by Borceux and others
[here](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/0022404989901473?token=6E22F569CA354F9721C80D762BE04F65C4DA782398803F6E5CE18B886406A3A2888D07980403789480906FDFBACFE486),  which describes **Quantale Sets**. The idea is to build quantale sets just like one builds localic topoi. What is interesting is that this cat is kind of a quantale version of a topos, and does indeed have an internal quantale which acts as a sub-object classifier. Problem solved? Not quite. I still would like to have a general way to describe "Qopoi" (this is my own pet name for quantale version of a topos)

Comment: A tautological note: quantales are described by an [infinitary Lawvere theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/infinitary+Lawvere+theory) -- i.e. a quantale is just a set $X$ with certain infinitary operation $X^\kappa \to X$ satisfying certain equations. So if $\mathcal C$ is a category with all products, we can define the notion of an internal quantale object $\Omega$ in $\mathcal C$. Moreover, the functor $Hom_{\mathcal C}(-,\Omega): \mathcal C^{op} \to Set$ lifts to a quantale-valued functor just when $\Omega$ is an internal quantale object.

Comment: So unless you can formulate some more precise conditions on the functor $SUB$, the answer to the question is just "for any $\mathcal C$ with an internal quantale object $\Omega$, we have exactly this situation by defining $SUB = Hom_{\mathcal C}(-,\Omega)$." For instance, we could take $\mathcal C = Set$ and $\Omega = ([0,\infty], \geq, +)$, and then $SUB = Map(-,[0,\infty])$ is some kind of "generalized subobject" functor. Perhaps you want $SUB$ to literally be the "subobject poset" functor? In that case, things seem rather restrictive...

Comment: Good try Tim! But alas (or perhaps luckily) the story is a bit more involved. I want a cat $C$ where the REAL contra-variant Sub(-) functor does exist, which in particular entails that C has some degree of regularity. Now, that Sub(-) functor does not simply land in Sets, but I want it to have a full quantale structure. Then, assuming that such a category exists (to be honest I have a few candidates, but I am waiting to see what folks say), I want more: I want that this "quantale-enriched " functors be repesentable, in other words that

Comment: there exist a quantale object in C doing what is supposed to do with respect to SUB(-). To be a bit more clear, what I am actually after is a "universe of sets" much like a topos, except its internal logic is quantale based, rather than heyting. Please take a look at the 1989 article by Borceux for some idea (take a look at my comments in the addendum)

Comment: PS why too restrictive? Please elaborate on that. To me it does not look restrictive at all, actually the candidate category is a generalization  of the topos itself (locales are just special varieties in the category of quantales). The topos is basically the classical-intuitionistic version of what I am after

Comment: Maybe not "too" restrictive, but it might be nice to have a bit more wiggle room. E.g. the poset of _regular_ subobjects might be smaller. As I think about it, I'm surprised how difficult it is to even come up with examples of categories where the subobject lattices have _any_ kind of multiplication on them not derived from the lattice structure. The closest thing I can think of is to let $\mathcal C = Monoids$ and let "$SUB$" be the collection of all subsets (not required to be submonoids) -- this has a quantale structure but is not representable.

Comment: Ok Tim, I think we are finally playing. Finally someone who is not scared to play! Very good. You are right, if C has only lims, colims, all that jazz, no way to get the TENSOR on subobjects. But how about starting from some C who has a tensor product already, say R-modules, and begin from there? R-mods does to cut it yet, but it will give you some intuition. Last note: you need to TENSOR sub-objects and get ANOTHER subobject.

Comment: Hmmm... If $SUB$ is really the subobject functor, then $\Omega$ must be a subobject classifier in the _usual_ sense. I don't know many examples of categories with subobject classifiers which are not actually toposes. I think I can show under a local presentability hypothesis that any category with a subobject classifier has disjoint coproducts and a strict initial object, which is a modest step towards actually being a topos. So most likely any example will actually be a topos where the subobject classifier happens to have an exotic multiplication for some reason.

Comment: Ok, whereas I have no doubts that I can have examples of cats where SUB(-) is what I want it to be, I have my own doubts about $\Omega$. If you come up with a proof of an obstruction, please post it as an answer. PS In the article above, though, looks like Borceux has a quantalic $\Omega$, so ....

Comment: @TimCampion so, looks like after your last MO  question and subsequent (slick) answer there is absolutely no doubt: there ARE cats with a sub classifier and with some limits which are neither topoi, nor are embeddable in them. The key point is that one has to drop the cartesian closedness.